# How to have y-axis label of two different colors in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, label

As my y-axis stays for two things in the plot, I would like to be able to have, on the same side (left) two labels of the 'kind text1 / text2' with text2 of a particular colour (green). I tried to do so by using [latex2exp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/latex2exp/vignettes/using-latex2exp.html) but I think it does not support the `\color` LaTeX command.
This is what I tried till now:

```
ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=1, y=1)) + ylab(TeX('\\text{text1 / } {\\color{DarkGreen} \\text{text2}}')) 
ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=1, y=1)) + ylab('') + 
  annotate('text', x = 0.25, y = 1, label = TeX('\\text{text1 / } {\\color{DarkGreen} \\text{text2}}'), angle = 90)
```

The second one fails miserably, also because it is plotting IN the plot and not outside.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25104213/324364) could be a potential duplicate.

Comment: There's almost certainly a "more ggplot2-like" way to achieve what you want. It would help to provide some more realistic example data and a better description of what you want to do.

Comment: I did not see that question, but the main answer is giving me back this error: `Error in set.gpar(x$gp) : argument must be a 'gpar' object`.